# How can I use same code in different functions in Symfony Controller?

Tags: function, symfony, controller

In my Controller I am using several functions. In this functions I am using similar code.

So I am wondering if there is a possibility outsource this code to not have to write it repeatedly. If this is possible, what would be the best way to do it?

```
class PagesController extends AbstractController
{
  /**
  * @Route("/documents/{slug}", name="documents", methods={"GET","POST"})
  */

  public function documents($slug,  Request $request)
  {
     $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cmf = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory();
    $classes = $cmf->getMetadataFor($relation_name);
    $fieldMappings = $classes->fieldMappings;
    $associationMappings = $classes->associationMappings;
    $fields = (object)array_merge((array)$fieldMappings, (array)$associationMappings);
  }


  /**
  * @Route("/blog/{slug}", name="single", methods={"GET","POST"})
  */


  public function blog($slug,  Request $request)
  {
     $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cmf = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory();
    $classes = $cmf->getMetadataFor($relation_name);
    $fieldMappings = $classes->fieldMappings;
    $associationMappings = $classes->associationMappings;
    $fields = (object)array_merge((array)$fieldMappings, (array)$associationMappings);
  }

  /**
  * @Route("/contact/{slug}", name="contact", methods={"POST", "GET"})
  */

  public function contact($slug,  Request $request)
  {
     $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cmf = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory();
    $classes = $cmf->getMetadataFor($relation_name);
    $fieldMappings = $classes->fieldMappings;
    $associationMappings = $classes->associationMappings;
    $fields = (object)array_merge((array)$fieldMappings, (array)$associationMappings);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not using `$page` in your methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword here is **services**. Move your business logic to a other classes and auto-inject it in your controller using [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html). This is a [Symfony Best Practice](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html):

> Symfony follows the philosophy of "thin controllers and fat models".
>   This means that controllers should hold just the thin layer of
>   glue-code needed to coordinate the different parts of the application.

You should read about these best practices!

You can inject services in your controller class and in a specific action:

```
class PagesController extends AbstractController
{
  public function __construct(Rot13Transformer $transformer)
  {
    $this->transformer = $transformer;
  }

  /**
  * @Route("/documents/{slug}", name="documents", methods={"GET","POST"})
  */

  public function documents($slug,  Request $request, PagesRepository $repo)
  {
     $page = $repo->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);

     $foo = $repo->doSomethingDifferentWithEntities($page)

     $bar = $this->transformer->transform($foo);
  }
}
```

Comment: If it comes to the question 'how to re-use code', services are your solution. If it comes down to just 'how to re-use this line', @Tomáš Votruba's answer is your solution.

Comment: I updated my question, to make it more clear what I mean

Comment: That makes sense. Read about Symfony's best practices, and start using services to get your logic away from the controller.  In your example you can start by moving your code to your EntityRepository.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will do exactly what you suggested. Thank you very much. What do you mean by "start with moving code". Is this not the common way? Or do I need to change this later?

Comment: I am using this code again for many entities. Then I have again many Repositories with same code... You know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. Interesting question! There are many ways to solve this and the best way depends on many different factors. You can create a different service and inject the EntityManager, or you can create a Service which you inject in the Repository class.

Comment: But in any case I need to start by creating a service, right?

Comment: In your specific example you can use your EntityRepository as well, which is a service as well (if you follow Symfony's best practices at least).

Answer (score 2):

You can use private method and call it, but in your case you could use `Page` typehint right in the parameter:

```
/**
 * @Route("/contact/{slug}", name="contact", methods={"POST", "GET"})
 */
 public function contact(Page $slug, Request $request)
```

Comment: This is a good hint! I did not know this. But my code is a minimized example, so I have more similar code. What does it mean exactly to make a private method? Do I create this in my Controller Page? Or on another external page

Comment: Create a class where you have utils method that you use frequently in to many sides

Comment: You mean the same like @Stephan Vierkant suggested?

Comment: He suggest a private method in your controller class because he thought that you only needed to use that code in that controler, but you are saying now that you have similar code in other classes, so create a class (UtilsService for example) with public methods that you need in to many classes and inject it as argument in the functions where you need to use some methods of UtilsService

Answer (score 1):

@Jarla Additionally to @Stephan Vierkant answer you can use [@ParamConverter annotation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)
In your case, it will be:

```php
/**
  *  @Route("/documents/{slug}", name="documents", methods={"GET","POST"})
  *  @ParamConverter("page", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
  */
 public function documents(Page $page,  Request $request)
  {
     $foo = $repo->doSomethingDifferentWithEntities($page)

     $bar = $this->transformer->transform($foo);
  }
```